# Regex for escaping single quotes which are not already escaped

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace `'` with `\'` but not `\'` since they are already escaped.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple with **lookarounds**:

```
(?<!\\)'
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iC0dU8/1).
You'll need to escape the backslashes as well for `PHP`:

```
<?php
$string = "I want to replace ' with \' but not \' since they are already escaped";
$regex = "~(?<!\\\)'~";

echo preg_replace($regex, "\\'", $string);
# Output: I want to replace \' with \' but not \' since they are already escaped

?>
```

See <kbd>[a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Un3rNM)</kbd>.

Comment: Be careful with this. `\\'` will not match even though it is the backslash that is escaped, not the quote.